# Adding a scroll bar retrospectively in PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, scrollbar

I've made a simple GUI with PyQt Designer and let it translate the .ui file to a python code.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(485, 785)
        Dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(485, 400))
        Dialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(495, 785))
        Dialog.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(1, 1))
        Dialog.setMouseTracking(False)
        Dialog.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8(""))
        Dialog.setModal(False)
        self.layoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 736, 471, 49))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layoutWidget"))
        self.SaveCancelLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.SaveCancelLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 8, 5, 0)
        self.SaveCancelLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.SaveCancelLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SaveCancelLayout"))
        self.saveButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.saveButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 40))
        self.saveButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("saveButton"))
        self.SaveCancelLayout.addWidget(self.saveButton)
        self.startLogging = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.startLogging.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(170, 40))
        self.startLogging.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 40))
        self.startLogging.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        self.startLogging.setCheckable(False)
        self.startLogging.setChecked(False)
        self.startLogging.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.startLogging.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.startLogging.setAutoRepeatDelay(300)
        self.startLogging.setDefault(True)
        self.startLogging.setFlat(False)
        self.startLogging.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("startLogging"))
        self.SaveCancelLayout.addWidget(self.startLogging)
        self.stopLogging = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.stopLogging.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.stopLogging.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 40))
        self.stopLogging.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stopLogging"))
        self.SaveCancelLayout.addWidget(self.stopLogging)
        self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.cancelButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 40))
        self.cancelButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.cancelButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cancelButton"))
        self.SaveCancelLayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 471, 721))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayoutWidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setMargin(9)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.commandLinkButton = QtGui.QCommandLinkButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.commandLinkButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("commandLinkButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.commandLinkButton, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_4 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_4"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_2 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.toolButton = QtGui.QToolButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.buttonBox_2 = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.buttonBox_2.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox_2, 5, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.buttonBox_3 = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.buttonBox_3.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.buttonBox_4 = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.buttonBox_4.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox_4"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox_4, 6, 2, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_5 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_5"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_5, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.radioButton_4 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_4"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_4, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_5"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_5, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_6 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_6"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_6, 3, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "MyWindow", None))
        self.saveButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button_Save", None))
        self.startLogging.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save&start", None))
        self.stopLogging.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Stop", None))
        self.cancelButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Exit", None))
        self.commandLinkButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CommandLinkButton", None))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox", None))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox", None))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton", None))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox", None))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "...", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None))
        self.checkBox_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox", None))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton", None))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton", None))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton", None))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton", None))
        self.checkBox_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now I would like to add a scroll bar that appears if the main window is being resized. In other words: if user resize the main window so that the size of content is bigger than the window itself, then the scrollbar should appear.
The more complex code of my GUI can be found here: https://snip.dssr.ch/?efe8c61b137f0751#IGcw4iGEOTHYlXTseCc+Z7tPDDPVtgAeAPx5A4P8pnc=

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`QScrollArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html). Instead of

```
self.layoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
```

Do something like

```
self.scrollLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
self.scrollBox = QtGui.QScrollArea()
self.scrollLayout.addWidget(self.scrollBox)
self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
self.scrollBox.setWidget(self.mainWidget)
self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
```

And then, for every line like

```
self.foo = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
```

You'll need to swap out `Dialog` with `self.mainWidget`, or add it to the layout explicitly.

```
self.foo = QtGui.QWidget()
self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.foo)
```

This could probably be done with Designer, too. I'm not certain on that though.

Comment: Hey @buck54321 - thanks for your effort.Unfortunately there is no QtWidgets in PyQt4. What is the eqivalent of QtWidgets in PyQt4?

Comment: Sorry. I''m so used to Qt5 now. In Qt4, you use QtGui. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hey buck54312: There is no attribute "setWidget" in QVBoxLayout. Should I use addWidget instead?

Comment: Ah. setWidget should be called on on the QScrollArea. Fixed.

Comment: Hmm, if I comment out the line `self.layoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)` and then paste your code after it, then I should do something with `self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 736, 471, 49))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layoutWidget"))` since layoutwidget is not initialized. So I changed `layoutWidget` to `scrollLayout`. Also I changed all `QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)` to `QtGui.QWidget(self.mainWidget)`, all `QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)` to `QtGui.QPushButton(self.mainWidget)` and `self.layoutWidget.raise()` to`self.mainWidger.raise()` all elements hide

Comment: all elements hide... so my GUI with the scrollbox is visible&scrollable but empty, so there are no buttons somehow :-(

Comment: You actually can get the whole code here: https://snip.dssr.ch/?ffc40f610034b32d#Ef7B9l4XBKD4UcbuC6+E67j7MPthMqWWovk8PulXMZQ= and the original (non edited code) here: https://snip.dssr.ch/?efe8c61b137f0751#IGcw4iGEOTHYlXTseCc+Z7tPDDPVtgAeAPx5A4P8pnc=

Comment: Hey @buck54321: Any guess how to solve this. I'm kind of stuck :-(

Comment: @MrPickel Not sure why things aren't showing up. You are right about the necessary adjustments to the old self.layoutWidget stuff. If it was me, I would just go through and make sure everything is added to the mainLayout. You may need to look at the docs for QScrollArea and set some additional parameters there. I don't have PyQt4 installed to test this stuff, but I ran a quick test in PyQt5 and everything is visible, albeit layed out a little funny. Good luck.